# UML diagram for main class

Tags: java, uml

How do I make a UML diagram for a main class ? I don't know which is the attribute and operation. I don't know which attribute and operation is public or private. This is the code:

```
public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pi = 3.14159;
        int radius;
        Area Ar1 = new Area();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choose which shape you want to calculate; \n1 Parallelogram \n2 Circle");
        Ar1.setShape(scanner.nextInt());

        switch (Ar1.getShape()){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Insert length");
                Ar1.setLength(scanner.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Insert width");
                Ar1.setWidth(scanner.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Area: " + Ar1.getLength() * Ar1.getWidth());
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Insert radius");
                radius = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Area: " + pi * (radius * radius));
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("ERROR: Please choose something else");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has no operation. It has no attributes. It's not a class. You don't need to draw anything.

Comment: Instead of UML class diagram you may want to show your main class as an actor (lifeline) in the [UML sequence diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used UML, and even when I did I wasn't very strict with it.

Since the class has no attributes and the method is static, you could just add the class name and the method name (unless you're not counting static methods in UML).